# I need help,Flutter permission issue.about Permission.location,Permission.locationWhenInUse.,Permission.locationAlways

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm using this plugin: **permission_handler: ^10.4.3**
Because I need to scan for nearby WiFi networks, which requires location permission. However, in my existing project that I've.

I've simultaneously applied for location, locationWhenInUse, and locationAlways permissions, but only the locationAlways permission is taking effect.

However, in a newly created project, I am able to request all of these permissions successfully.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZ2Q.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLZtw.png)

Comment: my  AndroidManifest.xml it was add code,but it's cannot fixit----->

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

For permission to handle things, you may need to write some platform-specific code into their respective Android/iOS folder.

Android (write in AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

iOS (write in Info.plist):

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>We require your location to provide you with turn-by-turn navigation and track your route history.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your location to offer location-based reminders and geofencing services.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your location to provide you with personalized weather forecasts and recommend nearby attractions.</string>
```

Reference link: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: thanks for your answer,but actually my AndroidManifest.xml I write all to need,but it cannot fix this problem.so I'm confuse.

Comment: Could you provide your Phone details with the Android version?

Comment: Android 13 ,my phone is Oneplus8Pro

Answer (score 0):

I tested this permission handling on Pixel 6a (API 33) Android 13. & it is working as documented & expected. That says that depending on the platform & version, the result may differ or vary.

Android (write in AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Lib (write in any .dart file):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            commonButton(
              text: "Ask for Location",
              onPressed: permissionLocation,
            ),
            commonButton(
              text: "Ask for Location Always",
              onPressed: permissionLocationAlways,
            ),
            commonButton(
              text: "Ask for Location When In Use",
              onPressed: permissionLocationWhenInUse,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget commonButton({required String text, required Function() onPressed}) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> permissionLocation() async {
    bool hasPermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus t0 = await Permission.location.status;
    if (t0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasPermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus t1 = await Permission.location.request();
      if (t1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasPermission = true;
      } else {}
    }
    return Future<bool>.value(hasPermission);
  }

  Future<bool> permissionLocationAlways() async {
    bool hasPermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus t0 = await Permission.locationAlways.status;
    if (t0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasPermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus t1 = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
      if (t1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasPermission = true;
      } else {}
    }
    return Future<bool>.value(hasPermission);
  }

  Future<bool> permissionLocationWhenInUse() async {
    bool hasPermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus t0 = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;
    if (t0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasPermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus t1 = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
      if (t1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasPermission = true;
      } else {}
    }
    return Future<bool>.value(hasPermission);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's true that I can request these permissions when I do this in a newly created empty project. However, when I add this code to the project I've already worked on, the logs it prints are just like these:   No permissions found in manifest for: []5 ; No permissions found in manifest for: []3; it only can found this locationAlways = PermissionWithService._(4);

Comment: In my project, I've also requested the following permissions:    var status = await [requestInstallPackages,Permission.bluetoothScan,      Permission.bluetoothConnect].request();           I'm not sure if there might be a conflict.

Comment: The issue is that in my already developed project, I can't acquire the required permissions. Additionally, the logs only show a simple statement "No permissions found in manifest for:", but when creating a new empty project, all tests pass and the permissions I want are obtained correctly.so I'm confuse.

Comment: Can you try to write the above code in your existing project somewhere and provide me an acknowledgement?

Comment: Sure, I added the code to my existing one – there are three buttons in total. When I clicked them one by one, here's what the logs printed:   D/permissions_handler(29617): No permissions found in manifest for: []3
D/permissions_handler(29617): No permissions found in manifest for: []3   D/permissions_handler(29617): No permissions found in manifest for: []5
D/permissions_handler(29617): No permissions found in manifest for: []5    The second button doesn't show any logs.

Comment: Which flutter version you've been using?

Comment: Flutter 3.13.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ff5b5b5fa6 (7 days ago) • 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0

Comment: Thank you, I have resolved my confusing issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I've figured out the issue.Because a colleague mistakenly added some unnecessary permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file under android\app\src\debug\ when they should have been added to android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
I could run a new empty project without any issues, so I went through files one by one, comparing them, and eventually found this bug.
WhenI removed the unnecessary code from the AndroidManifest.xml file in the "debug" directory, the program started running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue.Because a colleague mistakenly added some unnecessary permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file under android\app\src\debug\ when they should have been added to android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
I could run a new empty project without any issues, so I went through files one by one, comparing them, and eventually found this bug.
WhenI removed the unnecessary code from the AndroidManifest.xml file in the "debug" directory, the program started running correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).